# Cant figure out why x and y coordinates on my triangle class are are switched

Tags: java, debugging, implementation

I dont know if I did something wrong in my code, im testing my triangle class and for some reason cornerC of my triangle constructor switches the x with the y.

```
public class TriangleIsosceles {
    private Point cornerA;
    private Point cornerB;
    private Point cornerC;
    private int x1;
    private int y1;
    private int x2;
    private int y2;
    private int x3;
    private int y3;

    public TriangleIsosceles(){
        cornerA = new Point(x1,y1);
        cornerB = new Point(x2,y2);
        cornerC = new Point(x3,y3);
    }

    public TriangleIsosceles(int X1,int Y1,int X2,int Y2,int X3,int Y3){
        x1 = X1;
        y1 = Y1;
        x2 = X2;
        y2 = Y2;
        x3 = X3;
        y3 = Y3;

        cornerA = new Point(X1,Y1);
        cornerB = new Point(X2,Y2);
        cornerC = new Point(X3,Y3);
    }

    public boolean isIsosceles(){
        double lengthAB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2,2) + Math.pow(y1-y2,2));
        double lengthBC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x3,2) + Math.pow(y2-y3,2));
        double lengthCA = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x3-x1,2) + Math.pow(y3-y1,2));

        boolean isIsosceles = false;
        if(lengthAB == lengthBC || lengthBC == lengthCA || lengthCA == lengthAB){
            isIsosceles = true;
        }
        System.out.println(lengthAB);
        System.out.println(lengthBC);
        System.out.println(lengthCA);
        return isIsosceles;
    }
}
```

In my tester class I tried 

`TriangleIsosceles t2 = new TriangleIsosceles(0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5);
        System.out.println(t2.isIsosceles());`

The output was 
**10.0

5.0

5.0

true**

But when I try

```
TriangleIsosceles t2 = new TriangleIsosceles(0, 0, 0, 10, 5, 0);
        System.out.println(t2.isIsosceles());
```

The output is 
**10.0

10.295630140987

5.0990195135927845

false**

Comment: When I run that second test I getl  10.0  ,   
11.180339887498949   ,   
5.0    , 
false

Comment: Can you test one of your methods first for me: `new TriangleIsosecles(0, 0, 0, 10, 5, 5);`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Andrew, explain how this isn't an SSCCE.

Comment: @Legend Here is what I got:
10.0,
7.0710678118654755
,7.0710678118654755,
true

Comment: K, that's good then. Shows your methods are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first test does not actually create a triangle. The 3 points (0,0), (0,10) and (0,5). All of them have X coordinates on the same plane - this is a line. So your triangle class doesn't validate it is a valid triangle, so you end with a line that is returning true for `isIsoceles`.

Your second triangle isn't actually isosceles. The points are (0,0), (0,10) and (5,0), which does not have two equal sides.

Comment: Wow, im having a long day. Ive been testing my cornerC (x3,y3) with cornerB = (0,10) when it should have been (10,0).

Comment: Also, just as a side note, the no-arg constructor is a bit confusing. Those values will always be 0 ... not sure if that's what you wanted